# Force the module "legal" to show a "form_set_error" on path /user/register

Tags: 7, users, rules

I'm using the "legal" module version 6.x-8.5.
This is a great module, but i think there's a `form_set_error()` message needed, to show the user which's trying to register, why registering cannot be applied, if he forget to click the required checkbox(es).
I'm looking for a possibility to get this working.
Does anybody know where to implement this function(hardcoded, if there isn't a other solution) in the module?
I also tried to do this with rules forms, with this rule:

```
    array (
  'rules' => 
  array (
    'rules_register_ckeck_agb' => 
    array (
      '#type' => 'rule',
      '#set' => 'event_user_register_form_validate',
      '#label' => 'Register ckeck AGB',
      '#active' => 0,
      '#weight' => '0',
      '#categories' => 
      array (
      ),
      '#status' => 'custom',
      '#conditions' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          '#settings' => 
          array (
            'element' => 'legal[legal_accept]',
            'value' => '1',
                '#argument map' => 
            array (
              'form' => 'form',
              'form_state' => 'form_state',
            ),
          ),
          '#type' => 'condition',
          '#name' => 'rules_forms_condition_element_value',
          '#info' => 
          array (
            'label' => 'Form element \'legal[legal_accept]\' value check',
            'arguments' => 
            array (
              'form' => 
              array (
                'type' => 'form',
                'label' => 'Formular',
              ),
              'form_state' => 
              array (
                'type' => 'form_state',
                'label' => 'Form state',
              ),
              'element' => 
              array (
                'type' => 'string',
                'label' => 'Form element ID',
                'description' => 'ID of the form element to be targeted. Examples on the "Create Story" form: "title" for the title field or "body_field[body]" for the body field.',
              ),
              'value' => 
              array (
                'type' => 'string',
                'label' => 'Value(s)',
                'description' => 'Value(s) assigned to the form element. If the form element allows multiple values, enter one value per line.',
              ),
            ),
            'module' => 'Rules Forms',
          ),
          '#weight' => 0,
          '#negate' => 1,
        ),
      ),
      '#actions' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          '#weight' => 0,
          '#info' => 
          array (
            'label' => 'Set form error on element \'legal[legal_accept]\'',
            'arguments' => 
            array (
              'form' => 
              array (
                'type' => 'form',
                    'label' => 'Formular',
              ),
              'element' => 
              array (
                'type' => 'string',
                'label' => 'Form element ID',
                'description' => 'The element that should be marked. Examples on the "Create Story" form: "title" for the title field or "body_field[body]" for the body field.',
              ),
              'message' => 
              array (
                'type' => 'string',
                'label' => 'Nachricht',
                'description' => 'The message that should be displayed to the user.',
              ),
            ),
            'module' => 'Rules Forms',
          ),
          '#name' => 'rules_forms_action_set_error',
          '#settings' => 
          array (
            'element' => 'legal[legal_accept]',
            'message' => 'Please Confirm the...',
            '#argument map' => 
            array (
              'form' => 'form',
            ),
          ),
          '#type' => 'action',
        ),
      ),
      '#version' => 6003,
    ),
  ),
)
```

But this also does not the job, it should do.
Does anybody know what I'm maybe doing wrong here?
Thanx for all your suggestions.
regards
dennis605

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted my reply to you problem in the Legal [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1213432#comment-4744826) you created.

I'll go over how you would create an additional validation that will throw a form_set_error()

Create a custom module with this

```
function example_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id == 'user_register') {
      $form['legal']['legal_accept']['#element_validate'] = array('_example_custom_field_validate');
    }
}

function _example_custom_field_validate($element, &$form_state) {
   if (empty($element['#value'])) {
     form_error($element, t('This is my custom message if `Terms & Conditions` is not checked off.'));
   }
}
```

[image: custom form error message]

If you don't see the message now,  I am worried that you have error messages turned off.

Comment: works like a charm! Thanks for your support! That's exactly what i was looking for.